# getting 'Debug assertion failed' in visual studio

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, return, binary-search

I was practicing data structures and coded a binary search algorithm. The problem is, when ever i try to execute it, i'm getting `Debug assertion failed` error along with `Expression : format != nullptr`.

I've included a screen shot of the error.

Here is my code :

```
int binary_search(int demo[], int key, int size)
{

    int low = 0;
    int high = size;
    int mid = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (demo[mid] == key)
        {
            return mid;
        }

        else if (demo[mid] < key)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }

        else if (demo[mid] > key)
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }

        else if (low > high)
        {
            printf("Element does not exist");
            break;
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    int key = 1;
    int demo[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int index = binary_search(demo, key, sizeof(demo) / sizeof(int));
    printf(index);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Link to image]

Any help is apprecited.
Thanks

Comment: `printf(index);` -> `printf("%d\n", index);`

Comment: You've got a good debugger there. Use it. As a minimum you should find out which line of code triggers the assertion by looking at the stack trace in the debugger. You can also examine variable values and step thru the code to investigate. That is, there is alot of debugging you can do before needing to turn to someone else to debug for you.

Comment: If the element isn't found in `binary_search`, what do you return from that function?

Comment: It's ridiculous that the compiler built a binary out of this...

Comment: @kaylum okay i'm dumb XD. PS I come from pyton